# Properly formatting a table using Angular's ng-repeat

Tags: jquery, angularjs, css

I'm working in the AngularJS environment.

I have the following table of chart images which I'm converting to an `ng-repeat`.

I've managed to assign ONLY those records I want to display but using `GadgetIconsCtrl` below. Now I need to display two `<td>` elements per row.

How do I display two `<td>` elements per row using `ng-repeat` ?

```html
<table id="gadgets" class="propertyTable clickable_row">

        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-url="chart_treelist">
                <img data-draggable id="chart_treelist" src="images2/table.png" title="Tree Grid" alt="Hierarchy Grid" width="64" height="64">Grid
            </td>   
            <td data-url="{chart_pivot}">
                <img data-draggable id="chart_pivot" src="images2/pivottable.png" title="Pivot Table"   alt="Pivot Table" width="64" height="64">Pivot
            </td> 
        </tr>
              
    </table>
```

When the user launches the modal window in which this table is embedded,so I need to immediately *highlight* a specific `<td>` element.

Here's an example of a few `$scope.widgets` chart properties:

`$scope.widgets[0].title = "Bar Chart"
$scope.widgets[0].gadgetType = "chart"
$scope.widgets[0].chartType = "bar"`

So far I'm working with `ng-repeat`, but having trouble appying the `filter`

Here's the `ng-repeat` and the controller attached to it:

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('rage')
       .controller('GadgetIconsCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope',  icons]);

    function icons($rootScope, $scope) {

        var gadicons = this;

        gadicons.widgetSubset = null;

        if ($scope.widget.gadgetType == 'chart' && $scope.widget.chartType == 'bar') {
            gadicons.widgetSubset = _.filter($scope.widgetDefs, function (item) {
                return item.chartType == 'bar' || item.chartType == 'column';
            });
        }
    };   // end of gridSettings()    
})();
```

```html
        <table ng-controller="GadgetIconsCtrl as gadicons">
            <tr ng-repeat="widget in gadicons.widgetSubset" ng-class="" >
                <td>
                    <img data-draggable ng-src="{{widget.initImage}}" title="{{widget.title}}" alt="Hierarchy Grid" width="64" height="64">{{widget.title}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Your advice is greatly appreciated.

regards,
Bob

Comment: Create a directive on the table and set the cell classes from inside directive using a watch on the widgets object

Comment: you can have all those values in an array and use `ng-repeat` that way you would not need to add on every line.

Comment: You also shouldn't be mixing jquery selectors with angular. That's poor practice.

Comment: typically, when using a filter you can filter by a model. For example, you have a model='name' and then you have a ng-repeat. You can do <div ng-repeat="word in words | filter:name"</div> which will filter out the text you input. you can see an example here on my site with a bunch of words http://steveorrichio.com/games/w4w/#/dictionary

for you situation, you should make the filter...    .... filter:widgets[0].gadgetType

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I gave a wrong answer before. So, you want to change the filter type depending on your scope. Here is a working rudimentary fiddle that should help you abstract your answer. If you want more angular help, if you're interested, shoot me an email from on my site and I'd love to talk more about angular.

working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/E6aMZ/26/

```
<div ng-repeat"thing in things | filter:myThings"></div>
```

Comment: I'm going for the controller approach in place of `filter`, where I will just load an object of the exact records I need. Then I'll load that object on the `ng-repeat`. I'll post my final result later. thank you.

Comment: current problem is: how do I display two `<td>` elements per row using `ng-repeat` ?

Comment: to display only 2 per row, there is a limitTo:<number> parameter too

so, ng-repeat=" |limitTo:2 | filter:<filter>" should do the trick.  and you can do nested repeats if necessary